# Github reverse switch branch

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I was trying out Github desktop and created a test branch (BranchA) which I ended up creating a lot of code on.
Today I decided to backup. I loaded Github desktop, and before committing I thought it would be OK to move to the master branch, and accepted the offer to "bring my changes to master".
After some movement, my entire directory structure changed and a bunch of files were combined into a bit of a mess and I have 50 files changes indicated in the app. While some of the new content is implement, other older stuff remains - fair enough.

I figured this would be an easy reverse, but I've had a lot of trouble. I made a copy of the entire work folder in the new state in case I screwed this up. I then attempted a bunch of things:

Selecting BranchA in the github desktop asks if I want to bring or leave my changes from Master. Either choice here gives me about 40 "needs merge" errors.

I've then tried a few commands, such "git reset" and "git checkout -f BranchA", in an attempt to restore my work. Each time, I end up in a state where much my recent content is missing and the merged files don't return to where they were prior to opening the desktop app.

I would really like to know if there's an easy solution to reversing this silly mistake before I suck it up and just start coding again. Thanks.

edit: Here's the "git status":

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   a file...
        deleted:    more files....
        new file:   some...
        modified:   .....

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
        added by them:   Files...
        added by us:     A bunch of files...
        deleted by us:   More files...
```

Also:

```
$ git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

and:

```
$ git rebase --abort
fatal: No rebase in progress?
```

and:

```
$ git checkout branchA
error: you need to resolve your current index first
a lot of files: needs merge
```

Comment: I avoid most GUIs, including GitHub Desktop, as they tend to make these kinds of messes (the general GUI philosophy seems to be "the user is an idiot, so never let him know what we're doing, and do secret clever things behind his back so that he can never exit the GUI either"). But there is one ray of light: if you've made actual *commits*, *Git* can always get the *commits* back. You'll need to find some github-desktop expert who can tell you whether it actually made any commits, and if so, where it put them.

Comment: try a git merge --abort OR git rebase --abort .. include the input of `git status` in your question.

Comment: Did you commit any of this at any point?

Comment: Romain, yes. My reset restores the files to a value from a couple weeks ago but anything done since then was lost. I can see the new files in the master, but it's a frankenstein mess. When I reset, the previous commit seems to take precedence rather than an actual reverse of the "bring my changes to master". The reset therefore sheds all recent work.

Comment: The `git status` output is ... interesting, in a bad way: there's no merge going on (hence the abort fails), there's no revert or cherry-pick going on either, but there are unmerged files (!?). This is the kind of thing you see if something invoked the internal merge code, had it fail, and then just left the mess behind. The old stash script could do that if it was interrupted, for instance.

Comment: One hack worth trying: save the current index file (out of the way somewhere) in case it has something important in it: `mv .git/index .git/saved-index` for instance. Then run `git reset` and see what the status looks like: the (default = `--mixed`) reset will rebuild the index from the current commit and you'll no longer be in the middle of a failed merge-that-is-not-a-merge. If there was something important in the old index file, you can put it back and be back in the middle of the failed-whatever-it-might-be (the index file reset just built has no particular value).

Comment: So, if the reset gets you into a sane and useful state from which you can recover, that allows you to ignore / discard the failed-whatever-it-might-be index file that's now in `.git/saved-index`. If not, you're no worse off than when you started...

Comment: Thanks Torek. You're right. It seems saving a copy of the latest working directory, then resetting and then cherry picking my work between both versions was the best way out of this mess. Thanks for your help.